# Typescript Jasmine toHaveBeenCalledTimes() is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

I have a test in my typescript application:

```
    it("Should send current state when new subscriber is added (watching over file)",
            () => {
                runs(() => {
                    flag = false;

                    subscriber = createSpyObj<IPathWatchSubscriber>("PathWatchSubscriberMock", ["processNotifyAction"]);
                    subscriber2 = createSpyObj<IPathWatchSubscriber>("PathWatchSubscriberMock", ["processNotifyAction"]);

                    pathWatch.subscribe(subscriber);
                    pathWatch.watch(filePath);
                    pathWatch.subscribe(subscriber2);
                    w(() => { flag = true; });
                });
                waitsFor((): boolean => {
                    return flag;
                }, "failure", chokidarOperationDelay);

                runs(() => {
                    expect(subscriber.processNotifyAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedNotifyAction);
                    expect(subscriber.processNotifyAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
                    expect(subscriber2.processNotifyAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedNotifyAction);
                });
            }
        );
```

When I compile it into js, there are no errors. But when I run it, I have following error:

> TypeError: expect(...).toHaveBeenCalledTimes is not a function

How to test, how many times function of SpyObj was called?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) , and go to the section of "Other tracking properties"

You can try using the `.calls.count()` property.

So your test becomes:
`expect(subscriber.processNotifyAction.calls.count()).toEqual(2)`

*Side note - This is of course assuming your version of Jasmine supports this, which it should unless you have a REALLY old version of Jasmine.*

Comment: Thanks, your workaround works for me. One more thing, I switched from CreateSpyObject<T> to SpyOn and then used ".calls.count()".

Answer (score 0):

[`toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` was introduced in Jasmine 2.4](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-21). Judging by the symptoms - `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` did not fail, it looks like you have Jasmine 2.3 or older, upgrade.